# Use Jasig CAS délégation with 2 IdP (ADFS or others)

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, cas, adfs2.0, jasig

I want to use Jasig CAS (Apereo CAS), but in authentication delegation with IdP.

My question is : it is possible to configure CAS for delegate authentification with two IdP ? How can I do that ? How did the WAYF ?

And in the best possible way that must run with 2 ADFS :)

I see that (cas-pac4j) : http://jasig.github.io/cas/development/integration/Delegate-Authentication.html

But I don't see if it is possible to configure 2 IdP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I make my WAYF application with CAS 4.1.3 and Pac4J 1.7.2 and it works well.

My service delegates user authentification to CAS, CAS shows "wayf interface", user must select one link among two links - each link redirect to an ADFS 3.0. When user is authenticate, ADFS and CAS have SAML 2.0 excehanges, and CAS transmits one ticket to my service, ...