# JASIG CAS support for linking third party IDPs like Google, Facebook etc

Tags: single-sign-on, openid, cas, saml-2.0

We have local credentials but we would now like to enable our users to use credentials from other providers.

ie Click "login with Google" then ask if they want to link with a local account.

This seems like quite a common requirement. Do I really need to add it all myself to CAS?

I see people have done similar things, [Use Jasig CAS délégation with 2 IdP (ADFS or others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044240/use-jasig-cas-d%C3%A9l%C3%A9gation-with-2-idp-adfs-or-others) , but it seems like not a small amount of work to implement the UI to link/unlink third party authentication.

Any nice off the shelf code I could use (and help with)?

Cheers

Sam

Answer (score 0):

No this is called Delegated AuthN in CAS:
http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/integration/Delegate-Authentication.html

Supported since 3.5

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that just get you a principal marked with the third party name#id? We don't want our services to see these (just our local principal ids) so the big bit I think I'm missing is a "do you want to link your Google account to your local account" screen and actions.